# Eliminate Left Recursion in a Context Free Grammar

Tags: recursion, grammar, context-free-grammar, compiler-theory, left-recursion

I understood Left Recursive Grammar (LRG) and how to remove it.
But i dont know how to remove recursive grammar which combine both left and right recursive: 
A -> aAb | c

The full question is construct parsing table of LL(1) grammar of this: 

`S -> aABb
A -> aAb | e (epsilon)
B -> bB | c`

Comment: You cannot in general do that. Why would you want to?

Comment: I have to caculate FIRST and FOLLOW of an grammar.
S -> aABb ;
A -> aAb | e ;
B -> bB | c

Comment: Would you  show me the illegal way if possible ?

Comment: There is no way to do it. But there is also no need to do it.